# .htaccess force https for a backbone.js application

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, backbone.js

I want to change my current .htaccess which enables a backbone application to work without hashtags - to enable the same functionality but forcing over https... can anyone help with this please?

```
# html5 pushstate (history) support:
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forcing request to be HTTPS means you have to redirect the client/browser. If that doesn't mess up your setup, then all you need to do is add these rules right below the `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```